# send files from windows machine to a linux remote server java code

Tags: java, linux, jsch

Could anyone please share an working example of the java code which can copy a file from the windows machine to a remote linux server? 
 i have the below shell commands i am trying to include in java code-

```
FILEPATH="/E/Result"   
cd $REPORTPATH
COPYPATH="/home/hadoop/results"    
echo $COPYPATH
LATEST=`ls -lrth | grep -i *.csv | tail -1 | awk '{print $9}'
echo $LATEST
scp -i /C/Users/.ssh/id_rsa -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no $FILEPATH/$LATEST user@IP:$COPYPATH
```

Answer (score -1):

1. use scp.
2. start a python simple server in your local machine, and then curl in your Linux server.